# XSLT Filter Results

Tags: xslt

I have an attribute: `<names>Dan,John,Matin,Lewis</names>`

Can you create a filter `[names='Dan']` and get the XSLT to filter based on the list of values in `<names>`??

Comment: Please post your XML (and mark it as code using the toolbar button, otherwise it won't display). Could you also add your desired output? It is not clear what you would like to do.

Comment: `<names>Dan,John,Matin,Lewis</names>` is not an attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid also matching nodes that contain "Danny":

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="names[
  contains( concat(',' text(), ','), ',Dan,' )
]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your XML data? Basically you would need to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="names[contains(.,'Dan')]">
// do something
</xsl:template>
```